# Trying to access hidden <div> tags when web scraping in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

so I'm trying to extract some data from a website by webscraping using python but some of the div tags are not expanding to show the data that I want.

This is my code.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
uq_url = "https://my.uq.edu.au/programs-courses/requirements/program/2451/2021"                                           
headers = {                                                                                                               
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.27 Safari/537.17"
web_r = requests.get(uq_url, headers=headers)                                                                             
web_soup = soup(web_r.text, 'html.parser')                                                                                
print(web_soup.prettify())
```

This is what the code will scrape but it won't extract any of the data in the div with id="app". It's supposed to have a lot of data in there like the second picture. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sometimes you need to wait for the webpage to load, - which can be achieved with a web driver - I have also experienced that for certain elements such as `iframe`s you need to enter the `iframe` if you are using a web driver such as selenium

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean by need to enter the iframe if I am using a webdriver?

Comment: So this may not be viable for the `app` but here is an example for the [`iframe`](https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html)

Comment: Most likely you will need to wait for the page to load with a webdriver example : `WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.container-fluid#app"))).get_attribute("outerHTML")`

Answer (score 0):

All the that content is present within a script tag, as shown in your image. You can regex out the appropriate javascript object then handle the unquoted keys with json, in order to convert to `hjson`. Then extract whatever you want:

```
import requests, re, hjson
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs #there is some data as embedded html you may wish to parse later from json

r = requests.get('https://my.uq.edu.au/programs-courses/requirements/program/2451/2021', headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'})
data = hjson.loads(re.search(r'window\.AppData = ([\s\S]+?);\n' , r.text).group(1))
# hjson.dumpsJSON(data['programRequirements'])
core_courses = data['programRequirements']['payload']['components'][1]['payload']['body'][0]['body']

for course in core_courses:
    if 'curriculumReference' in course:
        print(course['curriculumReference'])
```